# Column statistics from given input file?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am given a .txt file of data:

```
1,2,3,0,0
1,0,4,5,0
1,1,1,1,1
3,4,5,6,0
1,0,1,0,3
3,3,4,0,0
```

My objective is to calculate the min,max,avg,range,median of the **columns** of given data and write it to an output .txt file.

My logic in approaching this question is as follows

Step 1) Read the data

```
infile = open("Data.txt", "r")
tempLine = infile.readline()
while tempLine:
   print(tempLine.split(','))
   tempLine = infile.readline()
```

Obviously it's not perfect but the idea is that the data can be read by this...

Step 2) Store the data into corresponding list variables? row1, row2,... row6

Step 3) Combine above lists all into one, giving a final list like this...

```
flist =[[1,2,3,0,0],[1,0,4,5,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[3,4,5,6,0],[1,0,1,0,3],[3,3,4,0,0]]
```

Step 4) Using nested for loop, access elements individually and store them into list variables

`col1, col2, col3, ... , col5`

Step 5) Calculate min, max etc and write to output file

My question is, with my rather beginner knowledge of computer science and python, is this logic inefficient, and could there possibly be an easier, and better logic towards solving this problem?

My main problem is probably steps 2 through 5. The rest I know how to do for sure.

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: If the number of columns is the same for all rows, you can incrementally calculate all of the metrics without too much trouble by reading the file one row at a time. It would be best to do this without creating individual variables (`row1`, `row2`,...`row5`) from the data for each row. You don't need pandas to do this (or even the `statistic` module introduced in Python 3.4). Alternatively, if the file isn't too big, you could read it all into memory which would make it unnecessary to process things incrementally (and therefore easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try numpy. Numpy library provides a fast options when dealing with nested lists in a list, or simply, matrices.

To use numpy, you must `import numpy` at the beginning of your code.

```
numpy.matrix(1,2,3,0,0;1,0,4,5,0;....;3,3,4,0,0)
```

will give you 
`flist =[[1,2,3,0,0],[1,0,4,5,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[3,4,5,6,0],[1,0,1,0,3],[3,3,4,0,0]]` straight off the bat.

Also, you may look through the axis(in this case, rows) and get mean, min, max easily using

```
max([axis, out])    Return the maximum value along an axis.
mean([axis, dtype, out])    Returns the average of the matrix elements along the given axis.
min([axis, out])    Return the minimum value along an axis.
```

This is from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html, a numpy document, so for more information, please read the numpy document.

Comment: by axis, are you saying I can access columns if I used say... y?

Comment: `flist.max(0)` will produce search by the columns, giving you the max values for all the columns in one row: `[3,4,5,6,3]` for above example. `flist.max(1)` will produce search by rows, giving you the max values for all rows in one column, in the form of `[3],[5],[1],[6],[3],[4]`.

Comment: Would there be a way for me to create the numpy matrix by directly reading through the data.txt?

for example numpy.matrix(readline... etc)

Comment: Use of numpy was perfect, i was able to transpose the matrix to get the columns to become the rows, then calculating stats as before. thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm glad that I was able to help!

Comment: Im gonna post the answer to how I did it just in case anyone wanted to see

Comment: Sounds like a great idea! That would make a great future ref

Answer (score 1):

To get the data I would to something like this:

```
from statistics import median
infile = open("Data.txt", "r")
rows = [line.split(',') for line in infile.readlines()]
for row in rows:
    minRow = min(row)
    maxRow = max(row)
    avgRow = sum(row) / len(row)
    rangeRow = maxRow - minRow
    medianRow = median(row)
    #then write the data to the output file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas library for this (http://pandas.pydata.org/)

The code below worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',header=None)
somestats = df.describe()
somestats.to_csv('dataOut.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it if anyone is curious

```
import numpy

infile = open("Data1.txt", "r")
outfile = open("ColStats.txt", "w")

oMat = numpy.loadtxt(infile)
tMat = numpy.transpose(oMat) #Create new matrix where Columns of oMat becomes rows and rows become columns

#print(tMat)

for x in range (5):
    tempM = tMat[x]

    mn = min(tempM)
    mx = max(tempM)
    avg = sum(tempM)/6.0
    rng = mx - mn
    median = numpy.median(tempM)

    out = ("[{} {} {} {} {}]".format(mn, mx, avg, rng, median))
    outfile.write(out + '\n')

infile.close()
outfile.close()

#print(tMat)
```